# URL of server changed from http to www

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Actually, I'm trying to connect to an external repository to get some libraries . I have defined in my settings.xml the server with the user/password ...

```
<server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>[user]</username>
<password>[password]</password>
</server>
```

I have defined a mirror ...

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Maven Repository Manager running on itd-dev</name>
    <url>http://ci-prod-nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

I have a profile ...

```
<profile>
    <id>itd-dev-repository</id>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>new itd-dev repository releases</id>
     <name>new itd-dev repository releases</name>
     <url>http://ci-prod-nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

And I have said that everyone passes through that profile

```
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>itd-dev-repository</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

When I enter via chrome or firefox to the url, and check the user/password, I can enter in the repository, but when I try to make a mvn clean package, I obtained the following exception ...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.ci-prod-nexus.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.11/surefire-booter-2.11.pom
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
```

The thing is that is normal, because , if you take a look to the url in the exception, he is adding www to the mirror url, and not using the exact url of the mirror I'm asking to use.

Why maven is doing such a thing ? I don't understand . Maybe should I specify some extra thing ? . I have tested with maven 2 and maven 3 and I have obtained the same results.

Comment: What is the behaviour when acecssing this URL from a browser ? DNS are often configured to redirect "non-www" URL's to the www subdomain... so you might indeed request to the "non-www", be redirected, and receive this answer from the "www" address.

Comment: When I access with the browser, I enter to the right place 'http://ci-prod-nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/' . DNS is not adding www